# Finding terms with missing opening brackets in a string

Tags: python, regex

In a string, I need to find the terms which contain missing opening brackets e.g. hi], hi}, hi)

I am able to find terms with a missing closing bracket in a string as shown below:

```
import re
missing_close = re.compile(r'(\w+|\s)?(\(|\[|\{)(\w+|\s)?[^\]})](\\|\s|\.)')
sen = "It is (fine [day]"
res_close = missing_close.finditer(sen)
for i in res_close:
    print(i.group(0))
```

Output:

```
(fine
```

When a similar regex to find missing opening brackets,

```
   missing_open = re.compile(r'(\\|\s|\.|\,)?[^\([{](\w+|\s)?(\)|\}|\])(\s|\.|\\)?')
   sen = "It is} [fine] day"
   res_open = missing_open.finditer(sen)
   for i in res_open:
       print(i.group(0))
```

Getting output with all terms having brackets

Output:

```
 is} 
fine]
```

Only `is}` is the needed output

Comment: @Wiktor I wouldn't worry about a single downvote, you get more than your fair share of upvotes, as so many vote on reputation. Answering in comments deters others from posting an answer while you work on your own answer. See [Comments are not for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
missing_close = re.compile(r'\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*]|\{[^{}]*}|(\w+[])}]|[([{]\w+)')
sen = "It is (fine [day]"
res_close = missing_close.finditer(sen)
for i in res_close:
    if i.group(1):
        print(i.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ebWo8H) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LK2AOf/1). The point is to match strings between closest `(` and `)`, `[` and `]`, and `{` and `}`, and capture the words starting with `{`, `[` or `(` or words ending with `)`, `}` or `]`, and only return Group 1 values.

*Regex details*:

- `\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*]|\{[^{}]*}` - strings between `(` and `)`, `[` and `]` or `{` and `}` with no corresponding brackets inside
- `|` - or
- `(\w+[])}]|[([{]\w+)` - Group 1:

  - `\w+[])}]` - one or more word chars and then `]`, `)` or `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `[([{]\w+` - `(`, `[` or `{` and one or more word chars.